# How I can ease out myself of .Rd file when I am developing an R package

Tags: r, r-package

I am developing my own R package using R studio 1.2.1335. Within R folder of my package, I have function r2.R for which I did not build r2.rd file in man folder. When I am checking packgae using command **R CMD ...**, then I got the following warning message.

**checking for missing documentation entries ... WARNING
Undocumented code objects:
'r2'
All user-level objects in a package should have documentation entries.
See chapter 'Writing R documentation files' in the 'Writing R**

How I can solve this isue ?

Thanks,

Mahdi.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions.

1. Don't export `r2`.  If it's an internal function, it doesn't need documentation.
2. Write `man/r2.Rd`.  Running `prompt(r2)` will give you a skeleton version of the file which you can edit into a real one.
3. Learn `roxygen2` syntax, and put that into your .R source code.  It can generate the `r2.Rd` file.

Personally, I generally do 1 or 2, but lots of people seem to think 3 is preferable.  Your choice.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and suggested solutions. Those were helpful.